# Normal variation or poor quality / craftsmanship on shingled roof

Tags: roof, shingles

I hired a company with decent Google reviews to put a new roof on my house. When the job was done I climbed up and looked at it. Some things didn't look perfect, but I don't know what's considered normal. Please look at these images and let me know if these are normal.

collage of shingle defects and odd shingle cuts
[image: collage of shingle defects and odd shingle cuts.]

Comment: That looks like a top of the line job if you can only find some minor imperfections in a few shingles and are concerned you need to look at more roof jobs.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed to hear. If you'll make that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The only odd thing I see is that they took the time & effort to cut a _very_ nice circle around the vent pipe into the shingle. Usually, they'll cut around the top, but then leave the bottom of the vent flashing exposed to the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photos look like a top of the line job there are some minor imperfections in a few of the shingles. Note how straight the lines are and the ridge, I have seen many worse jobs by top of the line pros looking around and even on this site the bad ones can be found but that looks nice to me.